# Kivy pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully

Tags: python, pip, kivy

When I try to pip install kivy on my windows 10 cmd prompt, I get this error

```
Collecting kivy
  Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-65.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
      Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
        Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

How can I fix this?

I wanted to pip install kivy but it didn't work

Comment: Try Python 3.10 instead of 3.11. It takes some time for all projects to catch up with new Python versions.

Answer (score 4):

Kivy is currently unavailable for python 3.11, it works just fine when using 3.10.8.. use an older version of python while waiting for them to be available.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this also:

```
pip install "kivy[base]" kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and tried everything but couldn't even install it, even in a virtual environment. However this command

```
pip install "kivy[base]" kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple
```

solved my issue.
Now Kivy is running without any dependencies.